# aggregate daily values to monthly for each pixel in a polygon using google earth engine

Tags: r, google-earth-engine

I am processing the NASA NEX-GDDP data on google earth engine for a polygon. This data has three varibales: `pr`, `tasmin`, `tasmax` and is daily resolution. For each day and variable, there are 21 images till 2005 and 42 from 2005 onwards.

My goal is to calculate monthly sum (for `pr`) and monthly mean (for `tasmin` and `tasmax`) in each year for each variable for each grid located in the polygon for every single image in a day. Therefore, for a given variable, a single row in my final output should look like:

```
 lat    long     month    year   ACCESS1-0' 'bcc-csm1-1'  'BNU-ESM'  'GFDL-ESM2M' ...... 'NorESM1-M' 
 8.125  108.875   1       1950   350          380           320         333                 322
```

The approach I am adopting is to write out daily values for each lat lon for each variable and do
the summing up in R. In order to write out daily values, I used the following approach

```
 // define which variable I want 
 var myvar = 'pr'

 // define my polygon
 var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([120, -6, 120, 8, 99, 8, 99, -6]);

 // Define a start and end date
  
 var startDate = ee.Date('2006-01-01');
 var endDate = ee.Date('2018-01-01');
  
 // Filter the image collection by date range, polygon and variable
 var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/NEX-GDDP')
               .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate,endDate))
               .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(polygon))
               .select(myvar);
  
 var dailyImg = dataset.toBands();

 var collection = dailyImg.sample({
   region: polygon,
   geometries: true,  
 });
  
 // Break point coordinates up into properties (table columns) explicitly.
 var collection_with_latlon = collection.map(function (feature) {
 var coordinates = feature.geometry().transform('epsg:4326').coordinates();
   return feature.set('lon', coordinates.get(0), 'lat', coordinates.get(1));
  });
  
Export.table.toDrive({
   collection: collection_with_latlon,
   description: 'tx_2006_2017',
   fileFormat: 'CSV',
 });
```

Each row in the resulting file is a lat lon from the `polygon` and the days are arranged as columns. So the number of columns  I have is number of days * 21 GCMs. This table can get very big column-wise if I increase the number of days

How can I write my output such that each row is lat/long and a day combination?